# Shorthand dictionary needed

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Do you guys think the poker stackexchange needs a short hand dictionary?  For people not used to poker forums, saying things like "Villian was OOP UTG when he PFR for 3x the BB" is confusing.  I don't want to turn people away from the site, but I also don't want to turn the vets away.  I think a shorthand dictionary page is in order here.

Comment: Like this? http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-there-a-comprehensive-source-for-poker-terminology/145#145

Comment: Ha yes, but a more permanent page.  We have a list of badges/tags already.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen of other Stack Exchange sites, we will want to add a link to the Glossary question to our FAQ.  Whether that question lives on meta or the main site is another question.  I think the main site would be better, because it can show up as a possible duplicate when someone starts typing a definition related question.

We should also probably change the title, from 
[Is there a comprehensive source for poker terminology?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-there-a-comprehensive-source-for-poker-terminology/145#145), to something like "What does [poker term] mean?"  This will give us the best chance of showing up as a possible duplicate.  Perhaps the Stack Exchange team can chime in if another title would be more effective.